# ON CASCADE DELETE implementation

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I am interested how the ON CASCADE DELETE is implemented because I would like to have some imagination about the performance of this operation.
Let's say I have 3 tables: parent, child (FK referencing the parent is ON DELETE CASCADE), grandchild (FK referencing the child is ON DELETE CASCADE).
Now I want to delete a row in parent table and also all corresponding entries in child and grandchild tables.
I would like to know which queries "are constructed" by ON DELETE CASCADE to perform this operation.
Is it something like the following ?

`SELECT child.id FROM child WHERE child.parent_id =  'parent_id';`   Then for each returned result from SELECT query the following query is executed:   `DELETE FROM grandchild WHERE grandchild.child_id = 'child_id'` ?   Then the row in child table with id = child_id can be deleted.   This is repeated until all children returned by the `SELECT` query are deleted. At last the parent can be deleted.
I guess it could be also implemented using some join on the tables, but then the foreign key constraints could fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is something the same on your example.
For more information about your queries. You can do something like this
`EXPLAIN DELETE FROM table1 where id = 1;`
to show what happen.

As you see on `explain` command, I also calls indexes when deleting child records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
So in the view of the performance, it should be the same as I described ?
Could you put a here reference to some docu, ..., which will confirm your answer ? Then I will accept your answer immediately.